# Inserting a dynamic document into MongoDB using the C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Using dynamic objects in C# with the MongoDB C# Driver.  When inserting the documents, the _id field is automatically generated by the driver.  Is there a way to get that _id value after the document has been inserted?  I've tried adding an _id property to my dynamic object before insert but that doesn't work.  The only other thing I could think of was to generate the _id before doing the insert (code example below).  This works and may be my only option.  I just wanted to post the question in case someone was able to figure out how to let the driver generate the _id and then retrieve it.  Although, whether I generate it before performing the insert or have the driver generate it I'm guessing doesn't matter?

```
public async Task Create(dynamic document)
{
    // generate _id
    document._id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();

    // insert document into collection
    await _mongoCollection.InsertOneAsync(document).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that when you just have new {_id =null} the type for _id is unknown. Try setting the type of _id in the dynamic class. Ex. ObjectId id = null; new {_id = id}

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex.  I tried that initially by setting the _id property to an empty string and and I tried ObjectId.Empty; NULL won't work because it's a non-nullable value type.  However, after setting the value and calling InsertOneAsync() it actually sets the _id value to either an empty string or to the equivalent of the ObjectId.Empty value.  The driver doesn't generate one for me and return it in that property which would be nice.

Comment: For me your approach is perfectly fine. The C# driver does smth similar on insert using the type generator for the id column.